# Can't get jQuery markItUp! to work

Tags: jquery, markitup

I can't get markItUp editor to work. My HTML code is pretty simple and it's copied from documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/skin/js/markitup/jquery.markitup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/skin/js/markitup/sets/default/set.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/js/markitup/skins/simple/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/js/markitup/sets/default/style.css" />

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){ $('textarea').markItUp(); });
</script>

<textarea name='comment' id='comment-input' class='text'></textarea>
```

Everything should be working for now, but instead I get this strange picture:

[image]

So here's my original textarea with just one button for Bold text. No errors in Firebug, and same picture in all browsers (opera, ie, chrome, ff). Can't locate the problem. Please advise.

Comment: You've verified, under the 'resources' tab, that all the resources are being loaded/found?

Comment: Have you modified /skin/js/markitup/sets/default/set.js in any way? The editor looks valid but it appears to be configured to only include the bold button.

Answer (score 2):

Try By changing jquery version file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Try Passing my setting in your code which is set in set.js

```
$('textarea').markItUp(mySettings);
```